# Debugging Javascript with IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I'm attempting to use the developer tools javascript debugger in IE8 to try & work out how it is unchecking a checkbox that is checked when a javascript function is run (no issues in any other browsers including IE9/10), however I'm having trouble understanding how to use the debugger properly.

When I enabled debugging it opens the window fullscreen, so when I set a `breakpoint` & go back to the page to run the function (runs when a file is uploaded via a browse button), one I double click the file to upload it immediately takes me to the debugging screen & won't allow me to get back to the browser window.

If I try & dock the debugging screen it comes up with a message of "Do you want to debug this webpage", if I click yes, it then makes the debugging screen big again.

What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to check the status of the checkbox after the script is run up to that breakpoint, but can't seem to do that.

Comment: @Shikiryu How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @Shikiryu What answer? TBH I already read that question BEFORE creating this one, it doesn't answer why I am getting the issues that I am - this site is such a joke sometimes.